# "recv" not working even though connection was accepted

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I was checking out a program written by a stackoverflow member **atanos** about connecting multiple clients to a single server in 2010, I modified his program a bit to accept connection details from command line, below is the server and cient code.

**Server.c**

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  fd_set fds, readfds;
  int i, clientaddrlen, portno;
  int clientsock[2], rc, numsocks = 0, maxsocks = 2;

  if (argc < 2){
      fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
      exit(1);
  }

  int serversock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

  if (serversock == -1) perror("Socket");

  portno = atoi(argv[1]);
  struct sockaddr_in serveraddr, clientaddr;
  bzero(&serveraddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
  serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  serveraddr.sin_port = htons(portno);

  if (-1 == bind(serversock, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))) perror("Bind");

  if (-1 == listen(serversock, SOMAXCONN)) perror("Listen");

  FD_ZERO(&fds);
  FD_SET(serversock, &fds);

  while(1) {
    readfds = fds;
    rc = select(FD_SETSIZE, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (rc == -1){
      perror("Select");
      break;
   }

    for (i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++)
    {
      if (FD_ISSET(i, &readfds)){
        if (i == serversock){
          if (numsocks < maxsocks){
            clientsock[numsocks] = accept(serversock,(struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr,
                (socklen_t *)&clientaddrlen);

            if (clientsock[numsocks] == -1) perror("Accept");
            else printf("Connection accepted\n");

            FD_SET(clientsock[numsocks], &fds);
             numsocks++;
          }
          else
            printf("Ran out of socket space.\n");
        }
        else
        {
          int messageLength = 10;
          char message[messageLength+1];
          int numOfChRead, index = 0, limit = messageLength+1;

          numOfChRead = recv(clientsock[i], message, messageLength,0);

          if(numOfChRead > 0)
              printf("Data Received !!! length: %d Message: %s", numOfChRead, message);
          else
              printf("Nothing read\n");
        }
      }
    }
  }
  close(serversock);
  return 0;
}
```

**Client.c**

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
  struct hostent *server;
  int portno, bytesSent = 0;

  if (argc < 3){
      fprintf(stderr,"Usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
      exit(0);
  }

  portno = atoi(argv[2]);
  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  if (sock == -1) perror("Socket");

  server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

  if (server == NULL){
      fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
      exit(0);
  }

  bzero((void *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

  servaddr.sin_port = htons(portno);
  bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,(char *)&servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_length);

  if (-1 == connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) perror("Connect");

  while(1) {
    char message[10];
    fgets(message, 10, stdin);
    message[10] = '\0';

    bytesSent = send(sock, message, strlen(message), 0);

    if(bytesSent == -1) printf("Sending failed with errno %d", errno);
    else printf("Sent %d characters", bytesSent);
  }
  close(sock);
}
```

I can see that the server accepts multiple connections but when I send a message from any of the client, the recv API in server doesn't read anything. The send API at the client is successful and I can see that all the characters were sent. Can someone please comment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're never actually putting the client connections in the read `fd_set`.

The line:

```
readfds = fds;
```

resets `readfds` to a state where it only has the server (listening) socket in it. You need to re-set each client file descriptor in the `fd_set` completely before calling `select`, each time around the loop.

Could be other issues (that's a lot of code to go through), but that seems like the most likely issue.

(BTW, I'm not sure that assignment is legal. I don't think there is any requirement on the implementation to have `fd_set` be simple, copiable struct.)

Comment: Or, he could change `FD_SET(clientsock[numsocks], &fds);` to `FD_SET(clientsock[numsocks], &readfds);` Also, posix demands that fd_set must be a structure, and I've not seen a *nix where it is not copyable.

Comment: POSIX imposes a struct, it doesn't impose that that struct not contain pointers. If it does, the struct copy via `=` won't do what OP needs it to do. That being said, I don't know of an implementation where the copy wouldn't work. Some environments provide an `FD_COPY` - on those it's probably safer to use it rather than a plain assignment.

Answer (score 1):

There were multiple error in your code. You were not using select call properly. First argument of select takes highest number of fds you are listening on plus 1. And second argument contains the list of fds to watch.

I replaced your FD_SETSIZE with fdmax. I corrected problems in your code and pasted below.

```
  8 int main(int argc, char **argv)
  9 {
 10   fd_set fds, readfds;
 11   int i, clientaddrlen, portno;
 12   int clientsock[2], rc, numsocks = 0, maxsocks = 2;
 13   int fdmax=0;
 14
 15   if (argc < 2){
 16       fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
 17       exit(1);
 18   }
 19
 20   int serversock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
 21
 22   if (serversock == -1) perror("Socket");
 23
 24   portno = atoi(argv[1]);
 25   struct sockaddr_in serveraddr, clientaddr;
 26   bzero(&serveraddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
 27   serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 28   serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
 29   serveraddr.sin_port = htons(portno);
 30
 31   if (-1 == bind(serversock, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))) perror("Bind");
 32
 33   if (-1 == listen(serversock, SOMAXCONN)) perror("Listen");
 34
 35   FD_ZERO(&fds);
 36   FD_SET(serversock, &fds);
 37   fdmax = serversock;
 38
 39   clientaddrlen = sizeof(clientaddr);
 40   while(1) {
 41     readfds = fds;
 42     rc = select(fdmax + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
 43
 44     if (rc == -1){
 45       perror("Select");
 46       break;
 47    }
 48
 49     for (i = serversock; i <= fdmax; i++)
 50     {
 51       if (FD_ISSET(i, &readfds)){
 52         if (i == serversock){
 53           if (numsocks < maxsocks){
 54             clientsock[numsocks] = accept(serversock,(struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr,
 55                 (socklen_t *)&clientaddrlen);
 56
 57             if (clientsock[numsocks] == -1) perror("Accept");
 58             else printf("Connection accepted\n");
 59
 60             FD_SET(clientsock[numsocks], &fds);
 61             fdmax = clientsock[numsocks];
 62              numsocks++;
 63           }
 64           else
 65             printf("Ran out of socket space.\n");
 66         }
 67         else
 68         {
 69           int messageLength = 100;
 70           char message[messageLength+1];
 71           int numOfChRead, index = 0, limit = messageLength+1;
 72
 73           numOfChRead = recv(i, message, messageLength,0);
 74
 75           if(numOfChRead > 0)
 76               printf("Data Received !!! length: %d Message: %s", numOfChRead, message);
 77           else
 78               printf("Nothing read\n");
 79         }
 80       }
 81     }
 82   }
 83   close(serversock);
 84   return 0;
 85 }
```